# Merging two content types in a view

Tags: drupal, view, drupal-7

In Drupal 7, I have the following content types:

- Project (which has a field collection of milestones which has a field collection of tasks)
- Bugs/Requests

Is there a way to list all the "tasks" by themselves and bugs in one view?

Comment: You want the "tasks" (which is a field in the Project content type) **and** the Bugs (which is its own content type) in one view?

Comment: Correct. That is what I want. I was thinking of doing a node reference in projects --> Bugs, but I want to be able to create bugs when creating a project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not very sure about this but you can use

http://drupal.org/project/nodereference_field

reverse_node_reference module enhances views with reverse relationships for node reference fields.